# How to change all fonts in chart?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, shapes

I 'm trying to change font in entire chart. Recorded macro using Shapes collection > Shape object > TextFrame2 (contains text formatting for the specified shape) > TextRange > Font.

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1502").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
  .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
  .NameFarEast = "Arial"
  .Name = "Arial"
End With
```

I checked it in documentation and it seems like good way, but when I try run this recorded macto, it throws :
**Run-time error: '-2147024809 (80070057)':** *Entered value is out of range* (my translation - I have localized version).

Error is on this line (especially with **TextFrame2**)

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1502").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
```

Because

```
set x = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1502")' is OK
```

But

```
set x = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1502").TextFrame2 'throws Run-Time Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Shape
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1502")

    With x.Chart.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
        .NameFarEast = "Arial"
        .Name = "Arial"
    End With
End Sub
```

I also suggest to change `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1502")` to something like this: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Chart 1502")`.

Comment: It works! Thanks! (Interesting - documentation says nothing about Chart in Shapes collection).